# Answer text disappearing in audit

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I failed an audit from the Low Quality queue, the answer looked reasonable to me when I clicked "Looks OK", but when I was supposed to "Look and Listen", the answer's text seemed to have vanished somehow:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9207557

Is it my browser, do you see anything? Or is it a bug/glitch?

---

Image for less than 10K

[image: less than 10K]

---

This was the answer, thanks for editing it in. I'm sorry I don't have a screenshot, but the "STOP! Look and Listen" page was showing an empty answer, only the question below was visible. That defeats the purpose of the page IMO.

---

This is a screenshot of a passed audit, showing the same problem as with a failed audit. Of course for a passed audit it's not that important to see the post again, as it is for a failed audit.

[image: Audit page]

Comment: It is a deleted answer, so if you [don't have 10k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) you [can't see it.](http://imgur.com/E9vUQfL)

Comment: Interesting, that was the post, yes. But I should see it if I want to learn something from the failed audit.

Answer (score 0):

That answer was deleted as spam and you said it looked ok. That is why you failed.

The answer disappeared because you have less than 10k reputation and you are unable to see deleted answers.

Comment: Yes, but I can't even see it on the "STOP look and listen" page.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed

Comment: Thanks @Andy, this seems to be the reason. But it's not only that I can't see it later, it was also invisible on the said page right after the audit.