# Can we get Franz Kafka out of the review queues?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, review-audits, low-quality-posts

Life in the review queue sure is [Kafkaesque](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kafkaesque#Adjective). I have been accused, but only god knows of what.

I [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9547128) an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615136/difference-between-web-services-and-web-application) in the LQP review queue. It was an audit, and I failed by not flagging it. The only problem is when I got warned I had failed the audit, the answer was gone and there was just a blank box. So on the page that tells me to "STOP! Look and listen!" there is *literally nothing to look at*. That is not how feedback is supposed to work.

Now I am banned from reviewing. When I press the link to see why, I only get to see that one blank post. I was under the impression that you had to fail more than one audit to be banned. Sure, I have failed audits before, but not very many lately as far as I can remember. Again, it would be nice to know what I have done wrong, but the site isn't telling me.

If this is a bug, then could someone please fix it? If this is a feature, then what on earth were you thinking? If this is a high school art project designed to make us relive Mr. K's experience in the opening pages of *The Process* through interaction with an arbitrary machine, then you deserve an A+.

I know this has been up before:

- [Answer text disappearing in audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302780/answer-text-disappearing-in-audit)
- [Is the "STOP! Look and Listen" broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272770/is-the-stop-look-and-listen-broken)
- [Allow all reviewers to see deleted posts they reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed)
- [Empty answer in failed review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253582/empty-answer-in-failed-review-audit)
- *Edit:* [Can we allow users with 500 <= reputation < 10k to view deleted posts that they personally reviewed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265380/can-we-allow-500-users-10k-to-view-deleted-posts-that-they-personally-revie)

But 100+ votes and more than a year later the problem persists. Maybe it is time to fix it? Or if that is to tall an order, could someone who has earned enough reputation at least post a screenshot of the answer?

```
</rant>
```

Comment: [Der Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trial) looks strange

Comment: The answer was spam - it ended in: *if you want get certification with job in Web please let us know by click the followig link [redacted]*... where the link was to a training site... See: http://i.imgur.com/hOEtQoK.png

Comment: @JonClements I missed that, so clearly I should have failed the audit. Bad on me. But how am I supposed to learn from my mistakes when the feedback I get makes no sense what so ever?

Comment: @Anders until some form of feature request is implemented you can ask on meta (as you have done) or possibly ask in [a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) which generally has 10k+ users and where such a query is on-topic.

Comment: @JonClements Perhaps it should be explained that is what you are supposed to do and why the situation occur? Even if the post can not be displayed, an informative little blurb could? A user interface that says "STOP! Look and listen!" and then there is nothing to look at is, honestly, not very good design. The existence of meta can not be an excuse to have an UI that makes no sense.

Comment: As an aside, the 10k min rep required to see deleted posts is daft. Surely you want new users to see what kinds of posts are being deleted so they can learn to avoid making the same mistakes. And the "Principle of least astonishment" is being broken as Anders has experienced when a post disappears before his very eyes. /rant

Comment: @Kev: In general, no. Deleted posts are deleted for a reason, showing them to everyone somewhat defeats that. Now showing you those you reviewed, whether it was an audit or not, whether you failed or not, that's a long-standing feature-request I support: [Can we allow 500 <= users < 10k to view deleted posts that they personally reviewed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265380) and on MSE: [Allow all reviewers to see deleted posts they reviewed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228955)

Comment: @Deduplicator - respectfully, I disagree and will leave it at that.

Comment: What a time for Franz Kafka to come up; I just finished reading CLOSURE, by _why, in which he specifically mentions having read Kafka the month of his jerktoasting.

Comment: I could swear we've fixed this at least twice... Don't know what keeps going wrong.

Comment: I would just like to point out that I have completely given up on the review queues, for several reasons, but the relevant one right now is it feels like *every single audit* I fail was resolved incorrectly, and browbeating me to boot, and why should I subject myself to such tsuris?  (There may be some confirmation bias going on here, but still.)

Comment: *"If this is a bug, then could someone please fix it?"* No, that creature is actually a person. :)

Comment: What a roundabout way to describe a bug.

Comment: Loosely related: [Audit answer with missing question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296135/audit-answer-with-missing-question)

Comment: Speaking of Kafka... and *bugs*... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis

Comment: @Anders This is pretty distinctly a bug since it's about an already-implemented system not working properly. You should consider re-tagging from feature-request to bug.

Comment: When I first saw the title I thought that for some reason you wanted a user named Franz Kafka to get a review ban ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643742/franz-kafka) is the only one with enough reputation to review). After googling, I found out that there is a [writer named Franz Kafka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka), so I guess you're referring to him, not the Stack Overflow user.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Oded implemented [Brad Larson's feature request this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed), which should solve this problem for all past and future reviews:

> all posts reviewed will remain visible to their reviewers in the context of the relevant review task. "Skip" does not count as a review for this purpose (or most other purposes).

[image: Oded in a pith helmet making review less Kafkaesque]

Comment: Wonderful! I definitely think this will make a difference for the user experience in the review queue. If nothing else it makes me a lot more motivated to keep reviewing. :-) Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid my reaction is the opposite.  Meh.  When can we finally get a thorough overhaul of the whole review system?  It still seems rigged towards alienating those who try it.

Answer (score 51):

I have a suggestion on how to fix this without having to implement a completely new feature that makes deleted answers visible for users below 10k reputation under some circumstances.

On the "STOP" page, perform a check to see if the element supposed to contain the post in question is empty. If it is, instead put a notice saying something like this:

> The post you reviewed has been deleted and therefore require at least 10 000 reputation to view. If you want to view it to properly understand why you failed this audit, please ask on Meta or in chat.

This could, for instance, be done entirely in the UI layer using nothing but JS and CSS.

**EDIT:** As Brad pointed out in comments, this is not an optimal solution. That would be to show the posts. But it might be a quick fix while we are waiting for that.

Comment: "*If you want to view it to properly understand why you failed this audit, please ask [somewhere else]*" - You made my day, man. That's just awesome, I had a good laugh. Joke aside. If "they" are too stupid to even provide proper feedback after yelling at you ... well, nobody forces you to do reviews after all, you know.

Comment: @JensG Nobody is forcing me, but I *want* to do reviews and I want to be able to do them in a constructive environment.

Comment: The single biggest problem I have with that thing is that there is too much hassle and too few incentive. A lot of users have stopped doing reviews. Wonder why?

Comment: @JensG So lets remove some of the hassle! :-)

Comment: I still think the best solution is to just show the deleted posts to reviewers, so that they don't have to come to Meta to ask about it. Saves everyone's time. I've tacked a bounty on my Meta.SE feature request to bring it a little more attention.

Comment: @BradLarson Agreed, that would be preferable. I was operating under the assumption that it would be hard to do accomplish anytime soon. Thanks for setting the bounty, I appreciate that. And thanks for the original feature request as well.